# Scrum backlog excel templates

Tags: scrum

I'd like to try scrum with my team. Studied a lot of posts about scrum tools here, but i think it's all superfluous and excel file is ok for product and sprint backlog. But it's problem to fing a good template. Maybe somebody could share excel template he is using for scrum backlog? Thanks.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Excel is really an extremely powerful tool and is very appropriate for the product backlog (and it has my preference if suitable: just share the product backlog on a network drive and there you go). I have used the following templates successfully in the past:

- Henrik Kniberg's [Index Card Generator](http://blog.crisp.se/henrikkniberg/2007/12/18/1197973740000.html) and a wall for the sprint backlog
- Petri Heiramo's advanced [product and sprint backlog template](http://agilesoftwaredevelopment.com/files/ph_product_sprint_backlog_0.03.xls) (video tutorial [here](http://agilesoftwaredevelopment.com/videos/advanced-excel-template-product-and-sprint-backlog-management))

You can browse my [personal collection](http://delicious.com/pthivent/scrum+excel) for more of them but I recommend the two above.

Comment: Hi! I am looking for something similar to Petri's template but for Google Doc. Any recommendation?

Comment: Sprint backlog and release backlog templates with burndown charts: http://www.phdesign.com.au/general/excel-templates-for-scrum-product-and-sprint-backlogs

Answer (score 3):

Don't have any templates, but what tool you use for scrum is indeed whatever works for you, so excel could be just as good as any other. Just so long as it's quick and easy for all to use.

I was taught scrum techniques using physical props. Sticky notes and meeting drawing boards. The idea is you use that for a while, and then see if you can fit it into technology after if it doesn't hinder the scrum process.

I'd just try and knock up an excel template that fits for you, starting from a blank worksheet and just build up whatever seems to work.

Though for backlogs it may be better to have a tool that manages it if you are going to have a lot of items, and especially if you will have many stakeholders inputting into it. Maybe a bug tracking kind of tool. Plenty of good open sources ones about. Don't know how they fit into scrum, but always thought the likes of bugzilla could work but haven't tried it.

Comment: Thanks for answer. 
Stick notes and whiteboard is good but unforunately i have not enough place to use it :(
We are already using TFS as bugtracking tool, thats why i think excel is best solution for backlog in my case.

Comment: If you use TFS: check out the scrumforteamssystem templates.  Or in 2010, the built in Agile template is now scrum.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know about scrum template in 2010.

Comment: Ooo, I didn't realise that either. Will have to take a further look at TFS 2010.

Answer (score 1):

I'll say it is a good idea to start for a couple of sprints on paper.

It will let you understand the process before having to fight against the difficulties in using the software tool.

On the other hand, scrum can be used for projects of different nature, and not in all cases will have computers available.